# Software center not loading software lists

Tags: software-center

I can open software center and the main page with a list of categories comes up but when i click on an icon or type anything into the search box the loading screen comes up and it just stays like that. Running 11.04. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running in terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

From updated comments as posted below, received the removal command fix from [here.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5415838&postcount=4)

Comment: Tried this and got this error after the first line.        Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ie.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: Try the updated copy with the rm command :P 
Located from.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5415838&postcount=4

Comment: Sweet! Glad to help ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can try to autofix the problemes with:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

It helps sometimes.