# Downloading BleachBit from Universe gets stuck at "Querying software sources"

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, software-center, bleachbit

I'm unable to install BleachBit on my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04. The Ubuntu Software Centre shows that the package is available from the Universe software source. After I click "Use This Source", it gets stuck while "Querying software sources".

How can I fix this problem? It has occurred to me that perhaps this could be from software sources being deleted in my configuration. If so, can someone tell me the default list of software sources?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bleachbit works fine on Ubuntu 12.04. If you dont want to use bleachbit, then install ubuntu tweak. it also has a janitor fuction which works perfectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Software center not loading software lists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46737/software-center-not-loading-software-lists)

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing `bleachbit` from the command-line,if installing from the Ubuntu software center not working properly.

Open a Terminal window (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>; or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gnome-terminal`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Then run these two commands (type or paste them in and press Enter):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even try it at this stage to put it on Ubuntu 12.04. It has got some issues and is not working properly. I updated my desktop PC and two laptops to 12.04 by fresh install and installed bleachbit on all of them.

Bleachbit would scan and do its job but as soon as it finished it would cause the PC to momentarily freeze then say there has been an internal problem with Ubuntu and it would send off an error report. This happened on the Desktop as well as the two laptops. There is obviously an issue there with 12.04 and Bleachbit. Every time I used it it would cause the same error. Not wanting to damage the operating system I Uninstalled it all three computers.

Having looked at other forums it appears some others are also having various problems with it. I will wait until a version for 12.04 actually comes out from the bleachbit website and I will try it again.

I have used it previously with other versions of Ubuntu and it has worked OK with them.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your system and make sure you have added the Universe and source respositories. This can be done with in the Ubuntu Software Center located in the Unity launcher.

After starting it you should go the the Unified Menu on the very top right, then Edit, then Software Sources. The second line ends with "(universe)" and the bottom line says "Source code".

Select both. You will be prompted for your password to make these changes. Close that window.

You should then be able to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net) web site, click on downloads, and get the latest version.  The web site always has .deb files for the latest versions of Ubuntu.